# How to count entries with specific values in R

Tags: r, counting

Let's say I have two vectors

```
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5) 
y <- c(3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7)
```

The unique numbers among all the numbers in these vectors are `1:7`. I know that if I use the `table` function in R, I can count the number of unique entries in each of the vectors. For example, if I apply the `table` function to the first vector, I will get

```
table(x)
#x
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 2 1 2 3
```

Applying it to the second vector, I will get

```
table(y)
# y
# 3 4 5 6 7 
# 3 1 1 2 2
```

How can I get it to count the number of occurrences of all unique entries in both vectors? For example, I'd like to produce the following results:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 1 2 3 0 0
```

for the first vector and

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 0 3 1 1 2 2
```

Comment: Why is the last two entries 0 in the first vector and first two 0 in second one?

Comment: Because there are no 6's or 7's in the first vector.

Comment: @MrFlick: post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, generate a list of the values you want to get counts for in both vectors

```
lvl<-unique(c(x,y))
```

Then explicitly list those values as levels of a factor before doing table

```
table(factor(x, lvl))
table(factor(y, lvl))
```

Answer (score 0):

table(factor(x, unique(union(x,y))))

table(factor(y, unique(union(x,y))))